# Can't get full second parameter in a for /f loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I've got a file like this:

```
001;0009;024;165748;0634;;CAPO;
001;0009;030;143366;0633;;CAPO;
001;0009;030;160671;0644;31/05/2018;PART;
001;0009;030;160857;0644;;PART;
001;0009;031;168135;0644;;PART;
001;0009;046;168085;0612;;CAPO;
002;0002;007;286169;4013;21/03/2018;PART;
002;0002;009;053175;4013;;PART;
002;0002;026;241075;4023;01/02/2018;PART;
002;0002;026;241076;4023;01/02/2018;PART;
002;0002;026;241102;4023;;PART;
```

What I need is to create multiple files, broken when the first 3 characters change, each one of them named with the 3 first character.
So, following the example, I will have

001.txt with

```
001;0009;024;165748;0634;;CAPO;
001;0009;030;143366;0633;;CAPO;
001;0009;030;160671;0644;31/05/2018;PART;
001;0009;030;160857;0644;;PART;
001;0009;031;168135;0644;;PART;
001;0009;046;168085;0612;;CAPO;
```

002.txt with

```
002;0002;007;286169;4013;21/03/2018;PART;
002;0002;009;053175;4013;;PART;
002;0002;026;241075;4023;01/02/2018;PART;
002;0002;026;241076;4023;01/02/2018;PART;
002;0002;026;241102;4023;;PART;
```

I partially achieved it with this batch:

```
@@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo Wait please...
set header=field1;field2;field3;field4;field5;field6;field7;field8
set craold=""
set cranow=""
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1,* delims=;" %%a in (myfilename.csv) do call :doTheWork %%a %%b
@echo Ended
pause
GOTO :EOF

:doTheWork
set cranow=%1
IF NOT !craold!==!cranow! (
   call :createFile %cranow%
   set craold=!cranow!
)
set recfilename=%craold%.txt
@echo %1;%2 >> %recfilename%
GOTO :END

:createFile
set myfilename=%1.txt
@echo %header% > %myfilename%
@echo CRA: %1
GOTO :END

:END
```

My problem is that in my files, I find just this:

001.txt with

```
field1;field2;field3;field4;field5;field6;field7;field8
001;0009
001;0009
001;0009
001;0009
001;0009
001;0009
```

002.txt with

```
field1;field2;field3;field4;field5;field6;field7;field8
002;0002
002;0002
002;0002
002;0002
002;0002
```

It seems that the "eol=; tokens=1,* delims=;" doesn't work correctly, forgetting that the second parameter of the "tokens" pragma should take the rest of the input line.
Why? Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you not just run this, `For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=;" %%A In (myfilename.csv) Do (Echo %%A;%%B)>>"%%A.txt"`, then add your header to each?

Comment: Drop the `eol=;`.

Comment: @AlexP, `eol=;` actually disables the `eol` character here, because it is the same character as (one of) the delimiter(s), which has got higher priority...

Comment: `Tokens=1,*` works fine, but the problem is caused by the unquoted arguments of `call`, so `%2` becomes split by the first `;`, which is nothing but a normal token separator in `cmd`; use `call :doTheWork "%%a" "%%b"` and read the arguments like `%~1` and `%~2`, resplectively, so the arguments are preserved...

Comment: I made a new test, in which I made a couple of changes:
'FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=;" %%a in (rapporti.csv) do (
set param1=%%a
set param2=%%b
@echo In loop !param1! !param2!
call :doTheWork !param1! !param2!
)'
well, the echo on the console is right, the two parameters are shown as expected. it seems that the problem is during the passage to the subroutine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not caused by `for /F` and its `tokens=` option string, but by the unquoted arguments of `call`, so `%2` becomes split at the first `;`, which is nothing but a normal token separator in `cmd` (just like <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,` and `=`).

To correct that, quote the `call` arguments to protect token separators and other special characters:

```cmd
call "%%a" "%%b"
```

And read the arguments like this to remove the quotes:

```cmd
echo %~1;%~2
```

Finally, let me recommend you to change your `set` syntax to this:

```cmd
set "header=field1;field2;field3;field4;field5;field6;field7;field8"
```

The quotes do not become part of the variable value here, but special characters become protected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my initial comment and given your new test, *as commented*:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=;" %%a in (rapporti.csv) do (
    set param1=%%a
    set param2=%%b
    @echo In loop !param1! !param2!
    call :doTheWork !param1! !param2!
)
```

There is no need to set any variables, *and therefore pre-set delayed expansion*, because your not modifying the returned metavariables.

You should doublequote your passed arguments at the `Call` command to protect special characters such as ...
semicolons, **`;`**!

```bat
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=;" %%A In (rapporti.csv) Do (
    Echo In loop %%A;%%B
    Call :doTheWork %%A "%%B"
)
```

In `:doTheWork` you can remove the surrounding doublequotes from `%2` as necessary by referring to it as `%~2`.

*I'd recommend doublequoting regardless of the content, however I've left it as that which is necessary based on the known information.*